# Find a schedule with lowest total penalty

Tags: algorithms, scheduling

> Given a set of n jobs with [arriving time, service duration time,
>   penalty per unit of time] find a schedule with lowest total penalty.

Notes:

- Arriving time is the time when objects aarivies to processing system.
- All objects can arrive at the same time
- Processor is able to process only one object at the same time
- Servicing time is the time required to process the object
- Penalty is calculated as (penalty * time spent in the system), i.e. departure time - arrival time

The easiest way to understand the problem is to imagin a loggistic company with a number of trucks that are waitings loading/unloading of the cargo. Trucks arraives at a given time and can wait on a parking. There is only one terminal that process loading and unloading. It's required to find an optimal schedule of processing.

Example of the input data:

```
t,tau,a
5,4,12
4,6,2
9,2,1
11,4,5
13,4,5
16,3,2
```

**The question here - which approach is required to solve this and similiar problems? I assume these algorithms are providing solutions close to a brute force.**

Comment: This falls within the topic area of job scheduling, in which there is lots of work. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is called "[minimization of total weighted flow time](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.09885)". It is very hard, especially when jobs cannot be [preempted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) by the processor. Even when jobs can be preempted, it is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness), so you cannot expect to have algorithms that construct optimal solutions efficiently.

If you are willing to accept non-optimal solutions, then there are efficient heuristics that find a solution of cost equal to $C$ times the optimal cost, for some large constant $C$, but they are not very practical (see the first link). A more practical approach might be to resort to a [local search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_(optimization)) heuristic.